# Modal.destroyAll() function works fine on Mac but not on PC, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

When using the function Modal.destroyAll() on Mac, all modals closes when session expired. I then tried it on a PC where the modals doesn't close. I can't seem to find out why that is. Does anyone know?

I tried three different browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) on Mac and it works as intended and two different (Chrome, Edge) on PC where it doesn't close the modals.
I have searched the internet for answers but it doesn't seem as if anyone else have had the same problem.

This is my code:

```
export const IdleCounter = React.memo(() => {
    const { hidden } = useInactiveTabDetector();
    const intervalRef = useRef<any | null>(null);
    const timerRef = useRef<any | null>(null);
    const modalRef = useRef<any | null>(null);
    const secondsToGo = useRef(30);
    const idleTimerRef = useRef<IdleTimer | null>(null);
    const routeHistory = useHistory<LogoutMessage>();
    const videoMeeting = useReduxSelector((state) => state.videoMeeting);

    const showCountdownModal = () => {
        modalRef.current = Modal.confirm({
            title: formatMessage(Strings.authText.main.idleTitle),
            content: formatMessage(Strings.authText.main.idleCountdown, {
                secondsToGo: secondsToGo.current
            }),
            icon: 'warning',
            onOk: () => {
                clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
                clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
                secondsToGo.current = 30;
            },
            okText: formatMessage(Strings.authText.main.idleOkText),
            onCancel: () => {
                clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
                clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
                secondsToGo.current = 30;
                routeHistory.push(routeLogout.link);
            },
            cancelText: formatMessage(Strings.authText.main.logOut)
        });
    };

    const startCountDown = () => {
        intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
            secondsToGo.current -= 1;
            modalRef.current.update({
                content: formatMessage(Strings.authText.main.idleCountdown, {
                    secondsToGo: secondsToGo.current
                })
            });
        }, 1000);

        timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
            Modal.destroyAll();
            routeHistory.push({
                pathname: routeLogout.link,
                state: {
                    message: formatMessage(
                        Strings.authText.main.loggedOutDueToInactivity
                    )
                }
            });
        }, secondsToGo.current * 1000);
    };

    const onIdle = () => {
        if (idleTimerRef.current && videoMeeting.session) {
            idleTimerRef.current.reset();
        } else if (hidden) {
            routeHistory.push({
                pathname: routeLogout.link,
                state: {
                    message: formatMessage(
                        Strings.authText.main.loggedOutDueToInactivity
                    )
                }
            });
        } else {
            showCountdownModal();
            startCountDown();
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <IdleTimer
                ref={idleTimerRef}
                onIdle={onIdle}
                timeout={TIME_UNTIL_IDLE}
            />
        </div>
    );
});
```

The version of Chrome that was used on both PC and Mac is 112.0.5615.139.
AntD: 3.26.6,
React: 16.12.0,
Typescript: 4.6.3

Comment: "MAC" is not capitalized: it isn't an initialism. [It's an appreviation of a cultivar of the apple fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McIntosh_(apple)), and we don't capitalize abbreviations, only initialisms.

Comment: Have you used your debugger at all - or at least looked at the browser console on both Mac and PC to look for differences? Do you have an ongoing WebSocket connection - or anything else that might interfere with session lifetime? Exactly what libraries are you using for this - or is it all your own code? Do you know exactly what JS/browser APIs are being used to determine session expiration in this case?